# I don't understand how this function unpacking works

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def average_cal(temperature):
    total_temp = sum(temperature.values())
    average = total_temp / len(temperature)

    count = 0
    for x in temperature.values():
        if x > average:
            count += 1

    return average, count

day = 1
temperature = {}

while True:
    user_input = input(f"Day {day}'s temperature saved: ")
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    else:
        temperature[day] = float(user_input)
        day += 1

average, days_above_average = average_cal(temperature)
print(f"Average temperature per day = {round(average, 2)} C")
print(f"{days_above_average} days were above average")
```

I don't understand how the line `average, days_above_average = average_cal(temperature)` works. I think its a form of tuple unpacking, but im unsure.Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Comment: The function *average_cal()* returns a 2-tuple which you unpack (correctly) into 2 discrete variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return average, count` is returning a two-`tuple` of `average` and `count` (`tuple`s, aside from the empty `tuple`, are defined by *commas*, not parentheses; the parentheses are optional if they're not needed for precedence/disambiguation reasons).

As you suspected, `average, days_above_average = average_cal(temperature)` is just unpacking that returned `tuple` into `average` and `days_above_average` in the caller's scope.

To be clear, the general term for what happens on the caller's side is "iterable unpacking"; it happens to actually be a `tuple`, but any iterable can be unpacked with this syntax, even pure single-pass iterators.